# Some .js files are getting 403 from S3 but not others

Tags: javascript, django, heroku, amazon-s3

I've got a django app running on heroku that pulls static files from S3. Until today it was working pretty well. I just pushed a different version (uncompressed) of prettyPhoto.js and now I'm getting a 403 on pages that try to load it.

The odd thing is that other .js files from the same bucket in the same folder work just file.

eg

this gives a 403: http://trainingflight_dev.s3.amazonaws.com/static/js/jquery.prettyphoto.js

but this works: http://trainingflight_dev.s3.amazonaws.com/static/js/bootstrap.js

I've looked at the permissions on the S3 console and they look the same. I've also tried re-collecting static files without any luck.

I'm able to reproduce this between my dev and prd environments, so its gotta be something I broke :P

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mind the capitalization. It works at http://trainingflight_dev.s3.amazonaws.com/static/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js.

Comment: thanks! I was just about to answer my own question with that :P (*&@#($*&#@$( that was a frustrating solution >:?

Comment: Ha. Don't worry. It happens to the best of us.